# Single device for digital to analog television signal conversion

Tags: television, coaxial-cable

Recently Time Warner Cable stated that for our area the transmission was going full digital and that individual converter boxes are needed for each television.  (http://www.timewarnercable.com/en/support/tv/topics/digital-adapters.html)

Does a device exist that can do the conversion for all channels?  This device could be placed where the coax run comes into the house, the conversion is done, and all the other TV's in the house could be controlled normally.

Additional question: If a single box would not work, would it be possible to have a passive converter for each TV so the channel could be changed on the TV and not with the box?  I ask this because devices such as VCR's, DVR's, and USB tuners would suffer from not being to change the channel through their own programming.

Comment: Are you sure you need conversion boxes at all? If your TVs are newish, they will probably natively handle an HD signal.

Comment: According to the TWC's website they say "If you connect your TV set directly from the wall with a cable wire, you will need equipment, such as a Digital Adapter, for every TV in your home."  This leads me to believe that a digital tuner would not work either as it would only need the coax wire.

Comment: What would keep you from selling cable to your neighbors?... If you find one lemme know ;)

Comment: With the current analog system there is no limitation against something like that.

Comment: @bmitch can you elaborate on why this is off topic?  I believe that I was not asking for a recommendation of a product, but just asking if it even existed.  I also listed the specific problem I am trying to solve by mention VCR's and DVR's.

Comment: From the [shopping advice meta post](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196), this falls under the "I need a product with these specific features" category. There's also the [meta post on AV connections](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/1104/2196) that this relates to.

Answer (score 2):

> **Does a device exist that can do the conversion for all channels?**

Not simultaneously, so far as I know. Typically a "set-top box" (digital decoder) can decode a single channel at a time. You can get two or three channel devices at higher cost but so far as I know there's nothing that simultaneously decodes dozens or hundreds of digital channels and multiplexes them into an analogue signal on a coaxial cable from which multiple analogue TVs could select an analogue channel.

So you have to use the remote for the set-top-box to choose a channel.

> **and all the other TV's in the house could be controlled normally.**

Not for choosing a channel

> **so the channel could be changed on the TV and not with the box?**

No.

> **I ask this because devices such as VCR's, DVR's, and USB tuners would suffer from not being to change the channel through their own programming.**

Annoying isn't it. Welcome to the future.

Answer (score 1):

[The fine print](http://www.timewarnercable.com/en/tv/channels-lineup.html):

> Some channels are viewable only with the use of Time Warner Cable-issued digital Set-Top Box; some other channels are viewable only with a TWC-issued digital Set-Top Box, Digital Adapter or CableCARD™-equipped Unidirectional Digital Cable Product (“UDCP”). Channels 100 and above require Time Warner Cable issued digital Set-Top Box, Digital Adapter or CableCARD™-equipped Unidirectional Digital Cable Product (“UDCP”), or a QAM tuner.

Otherwise it'd be 'free'; you're talking about a **black box** and asking how to decrypt intentionally encrypted signals; the only reason these "set top boxes" exist these days: *muney*.

All analog devices will need some sort of digital device to tune a digital signal. If a device such as what you want exists, I'd assume it to be a multi thousand dollar item (and quite possibly illegal to sell or use in the US); just rent the boxes from the company.

A universal remote (and all its accompanying headaches) is as best as you're going to get I think.

---

> Digital Adapters do not support channels in the Preferred TV plan, the on-screen guide, or other interactive features. **You can find your local channel lineup**, which indicates channels not available with Digital Adapters, by clicking on the blue "Download PDF" link on the Channel Finder page.

*I need a method to allow a DVR/VCR to work with only a digital signal from TWC.*

I would assume that without a Digital Adapter, all you will get (on a digitally tuned television/DVR) is your local 'broadcast' programing. Note, I haven't hooked up a TV in a long time. They might have the local channels on lock-down now too: (but not if you have a QAM*)

"I have found many channels still being broadcast with a 10$ converter that was available just prior to the change. After moving last year I have no signal from these boxes." –Ed Beal

---

*Or buy a device with a QAM Tuner (to receive free local channels without a box, *in conjunction with your paid subscription*): [How to get 'free' HD with a QAM tuner](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-get-free-hd-with-a-qam-tuner/) –Cnet

> Many cable providers offer few or no details about unencrypted QAM channels. **It is also common for cable providers to falsely insist** that a set top box from the cable company is required to watch all digital cable channels, including unencrypted channels, even though QAM channels may be distributed via their system. QAM channels may move without notification and some channels may have strange numbering schemes. –Wiki, [QAM television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QAM_%28television%29)

So, a DVR/VCR *with a QAM tuner* will work with the digital signal from TWC but it will only provide you with the QAM channels. Again, the name of the game is *muney*.

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to give you the bounty as the question was put on hold.

Comment: Truly, it's the sentiment that counts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with Cablevision, you will need a converter box for each TV.  A single box won't work because the cable digital signals are not compatible with over the air digital broadcasts. Thus your TV cannot directly receive signals from the digital cable network.  The converter box is needed to convert the cable signals into signals compatible with your TV, select the channels, and limit your reception to those channels that you have signed up for.

Comment: They do want the $ per tv. But I have found many channels still being broadcast with a 10$ converter that was available just prior to the change. After moving last year I have no signal from these boxes and had to get a dish because my place is  close to no place.